# which IP address should I make in the Post method?

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, api

I made an API between an android application and a desktop application (java). I test that in local between android studio device and my desktop application and it works with local address:

```
post("http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/v1/locations", json)
```

but now I want to install the app in my phone so I'm not in local anymore, I want to know which address should I make to post from my phone to my laptop java application?

Comment: _my phone to my laptop java application_ are those under same network?

Comment: If you are on the same network, for example via wifi, you can use the ip your laptop has on that network (if client isolation is not active in that wifi).

Comment: Yes I try this and it works ,But there is no solution to do that out of my network ? any idea ?

Comment: Depends on where the server is hosted. The server will need a static IP (or you could use a dynamic dns service). If you are hosting it on your private network (for example at home) you might have to forward a port in your router to your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deploy your service that you have created on some server then you can access same.

so the IP you need to use of server.

Comment: ah ok thanks , do you have any toturial to create a server ?

Comment: you need to purchase same or can use aws for testing perpose its free for 1 year
https://aws.amazon.com/console/